# why does the font on my webpage turn blue for no reason?

Tags: html, css

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlqYk.png)

the title. why does only my navbar text turn blue? i just don't understand.
here's the html for the navbar with the blue:

```
 <navbar>
        <object class="navLogo" data="../images/defavatar.png" width="45px" height="45px"></object>
        <a href="./teams">Teams</a>
        <a href="./challenges">Challenges</a>
        <a href="./faq">FAQ</a>
        <a href="./login" class="loginButton">Login</a>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='./register';">Join Now</button>
    </navbar>
```

and here's the related css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Anek";
    src: url("../fonts/AnekLatin-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf");
}


body {
    background-color: #1b161d;
    color: #ece8ed;
    font-family: Anek;
}

navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

moving the `color` from body to navbar fixed it, but why?

Comment: In most browsers, links are displayed in blue unless you sign another color.

Comment: @not2savvy i'm so stupid thanks. can you make this an answer so i can accept it

Comment: There is no such thing as a stupid question! ;-)